# html select multiple

Tags: html, webforms

I have a select element with 20+ options and size 10. I do not have the multiple attribute on the select. However a tester is able to select multiple options. The tester is using IE7 on Win XP.

How is this possible?

Could the tester have a client override to enable this?

**Update:**
In response to most of the comments.

- The select element isnt posted back its just used in some UI and javascript.
- The tester isnt doing anything out of the ordinary (firebug, headers)
- the html is your standard select element with a size attribute of 10 on it.

Comment: How do you know he can select multiple option ?

Comment: In theory, of course, but I can't think of a *legitimate* way (like a input helper or something)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tester might be playing around with the request headers, changing the number of options directly on them.

Another way to do this is use firebug/ie developer tools and dynamically add a `multiple="multiple"` attribute to the select, then select several options.

These are just *two* ways off the top of my head. Your tested might be doing something else entirely.

There is a reason why the phrase "never trust the client" is so popular.

Comment: I know for a fact that the tester isn't doing anything like the above. They just visit the page and are able to select multiple options.

Comment: @CeejeeB - can you post the HTML of the select (in the question)?

Comment: @CeejeeB - Can you please _edit your question_ and add the _whole_ select (opening, closing and all the options inside).

Comment: <select name="TermsListBox" class="ListBox" id="TermsListBox" size="10"><option>...</option></select>

Comment: @CeejeeB - What does the tester actually do to select multiple options?

Comment: Just uses the shift and control keys as if the multiple attribute was present.

Comment: @CeejeeB - you indicate that javascript is involved. Can you please edit your question and add the markup for the select and post the javascript involved?

Answer (score 1):

The client can override anything they want - by sending them the HTML to render the form, you are guaranteeing nothing about what will be sent back.

You should be parsing the information being sent back and checking for validity - if you expect only one value for that form input element, either error or drop the additional values.

Comment: The select is not posted back, its just used in some javascript ui and know for a fact that the tester isn't doing anything like the above. They just visit the page and are able to select multiple options.

Comment: @CeejeeB We'll need to see this JavaScript then :)

Comment: The javascript isn't doing anything. It only fires when a button is pressed and that is done later. The tester can select multiple items from the off.

Answer (score 0):

**You need to check everything on the server**

Simple! You can't trust anything coming from the browser.  If you expected one item to be selected, then check it on the server and display a message if not.

You're tester has uncovered a fundamental security issue with your site and I'd thank them for this.

Comment: I understand and support your point, but that wasn't the question. I need to know how a client can select multiple items out of a select when the multiple attribute isn't present.

Comment: Because the browser can do whatever it wants.  HTML is simply a mark-up, its totally up to the browser whether to follow it or not.  Your tester is likely doing something you're not expecting them to do

Comment: Yes, so is there a known bug with ie 7 relating to this issue?